# Unable to excel sheet into datatable

Tags: asp.net

I am unable to read excel sheet to data table which has change in orientation
for reference of excel sheet i am trying to upload in asp.net

### i have attached image below

### sheet i am uploading as u can see hub location,region ,location column is not oriented So data table is not able to get the results

[image: sheet i am uploading as u can see hub location column is not oriented So data table is not able to get the results]

**For more help i am even uploading the generated DATA TABLE IMAGE of above excel sheet**

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you put your code here? what you tried?

Comment: OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]", oledbConn);
OleDbDataAdapter oleda = new OleDbDataAdapter();
oleda.SelectCommand = cmd;
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
oleda.Fill(ds);
ExcelSheetData = ds.Tables[0];]

Answer (score 0):

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]", oledbConn); 
OleDbDataAdapter oleda = new OleDbDataAdapter(); 
oleda.SelectCommand = cmd; 
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
oleda.Fill(ds, "XLData");
ExcelSheetData = ds.Tables[0];
```

Try this, because you need to give Name of the source table to use for table mapping.

Comment: No its not working still few feilds in data table are empty. For which column is not alligned